# Calculating Percetange Based on Aggregate Total

Tags: sql-server

I currently have the query below to look at sales by city - excluding London.

```
SELECT
City, 
SUM(Sales) as Total
FROM Employees
WHERE City != 'London'
Group BY City
```

**Current Output**

```
City            Total    
Kirkland          3         
Redmond           4         
Seattle           9        
Tacoma            2
```

I need to create the third column "Percentage" below (%, no decimal points). Could you please help me with this? Thank you so much in advance!

**Desired Output**

```
City            Total    Percentage
Kirkland          3         17%
Redmond           4         22%
Seattle           9         50%
Tacoma            2         11%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below query.

```
SELECT
City, 
SUM(Sales) as Total
FROM Employees
WHERE City != 'London'
Group BY City

The result will be;
   City            Total
   Kirkland          3
   Redmond           4
   Seattle           9
   Tacoma            2
```

To calculate the percentage,

```
DECLARE @Total INT
SELECT @Total=SUM(Sales) FROM Employees WHERE City != 'London'

SELECT
 City, 
 SUM(Sales) as Total,
 CAST(SUM(Sales) * 100 / CAST(@Total AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS DECIMAL (18,2))
FROM Employees
WHERE City != 'London'
Group BY City
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my first question! I've added a new question to my post, which is calculating percentage based on the aggregate total (excluding London). Is there a way to calculate this?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: CAST(SUM(Sales) * 100 / CAST(@Total AS VARCHAR(8)) AS VARCHAR(8)) + '%'  , I used this instead to get "%" :) Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

change the `ELSE` part to 0

```
SELECT
City, 
SUM(CASE WHEN City <> 'London' THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) as Total
FROM Employees
Group BY City
```

or why not exclude `City` with `London` value

```
SELECT
       City, 
       SUM(Sales) as Total
FROM   Employees
Where  City <> 'London'
GROUP BY City
```